# Is there a way to break through bosses' "flash block"?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

When fighting the last bosses like Goro, Kintaro, and Shao Khan, hitting them often results in them executing some "flash block" where their body flashes white on contact.  They don't even go into actual block mode.  During this flash block, it seems as though they take normal physical damage, but they aren't knocked back or otherwise affected by the attack (ie, except for the damage, it's as if you never even hit them).

This is annoying, especially when you're trying to get out a good combo.  You can be mid combo and they'll start flashing white and pummel you without actually breaking your combo.  They just act as if you're not doing anything to them at all.  Either there's a way to break this boss block or it's just a cheap way to make the game harder without having to invest more research into legitimate AI.

Comment: It's almost certainly that last bit.

Comment: I think that happens when you hit them during their attack.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the "flash-block" you're referring to is actually called "armour" in fighting games.

This happens when a character uses a special move that is armoured, which means that if you hit them while they're doing this move, they flash to signify they've lost a layer of armour (certain moves could have 1 stack or armour, or more!). They take damage from your attack but are not staggered and carry on what they're doing.

You can't really avoid armour as an armoured move is usually thrown out in anticipation/response to your attack. If you are using a character that can hit multiple times very fast, you could try to break through their armour. I don't think armoured moves can absorb grabs, so you could try grabbing. I'm not sure about Mortal Kombat, but in Injustice some characters have access to armour-breaking moves. So if there is a character in MK9 that can do this you might try using them.

I only just read specifically when it's happening to you. The bosses in MK9 are very cheap. You can try dropping combos early, if the boss tries to do this breakout move you should be able to punish it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to ignore the "flash block" effect is to attack them from the back.
Jump or teleport behind the enemy while they casting a special attack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mechanic known as "super armor" in some games. Basically, the boss will take damage, but will not flinch, and instead continue with whatever he was doing. Shao Kahn gains super armor when using his Hammer Throw, for example. Wait the attack out and counter-attack.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need.
The bosses have one super weakness. Get near and permanently jump over them. As soon as they do anything else then block or some movement-attack use the timeframe and land a combo or uppercut. Rinse and Repeat.